# eps exported graph from matlab

Tags: floats, eps, matlab

I dont know what is the problem with the eps graph exported from Matlab, when i do the run the figure is not in its position as seen below [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{epsf,epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{cite}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.05in}
\setlength{\textheight}{240mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\pagestyle{plain}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}
\newtheorem*{Proof*}{Proof}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{Proof}{section}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics{fig/Fig.(6.1)(a).eps}
\caption{latexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatelatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatex}
\label{fig:Fig.(6.1)(a)}
\end{figure}


latexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlatexlat

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check the bounding box of the .eps

Comment: I dont think so cuz i tried it in my friend  pc (without downloading all the packages) some packages is making this mess in my pc

Comment: In ths case, the best solution consists in commenting out all packages that seem unnecessary so as to compile nicely, then uncomment them gradually until you have error messages again, to identify the culprit. Sometimes it may be the loading order, or an obsolete package.